# Raspberry Pi Zero W won't connect to network

Tags: networking, pi-zero

I have a NetGear modem/router (2.4G) connected with a TP-Link AX1800 Wifi 6 router (2.4g and 5g networks) connected to it with an ethernet cable.

I tried connecting my Pi (headless) to the 2.4g TP-Link Network and couldn't get it to work using Raspbian with a wpa_supplicant.conf & blank ssh on /boot/ and then trying PiBakery. When I plug the SD card back into the laptop the wpa_supplicant and ssh files disappear appropriately so it's booting. I also tested using an HDMI and monitor so Rasbian works but the wifi doesn't for some reason.

All of my home devices are connected to the TP-Link router no problem. Is it possible that the NetGear router being chained to it is causing an issue? It still has an old 2.4G ssid running on it with a different name than my TP-Link 2.4G ssid. All networks are not hidden. Not sure if that would somehow cause any issues.

I tried researching and googling and couldn't find an answer. I'm out of ideas on why my pi can't connect to the network...thoughts?

Here's my supplicant if anyone's curious but i dont think that's causing the issue:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=us

network={
    ssid="TPLink2.4G"
    psk="password123"
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

I also tried:

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=US

network={
    ssid="TPLink2.4G"
    psk="password123"
}
```

Comment: DHCP server isn't showing the Pi on my TP-Link router settings

Answer (score 1):

A Raspberry PI network configuration guide is here

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/computers/configuration.html#configuring-networking31

Troubleshooting tips

- Double-check that the file was written in plaintext, with no special characters.
- Double-check that the file has disappeared from your boot
  directory.
- Connect the Pi to a TV or monitor via HDMI to make sure it’s booting normally.
- If you’re employing a Raspberry Pi Zero W, confirm you’re attempting to attach to a 2.4GHz network (the Zero doesn’t support 5G).
- If you’re employing a Raspberry Pi Zero, confirm it is a Raspberry Pi Zero W, not a basic Zero (only the W supports wifi and Bluetooth). The version and the model are on the PCB.

Another problem that unfortunately affects some versions of Raspbian/Rasperry Pi OS is that the `rfkill` status of the Wi-Fi interface is not unblocked so the wifi doesn't connect. This can be checked by logging in on the console and running:

```
rfkill
```

For the Wi-Fi to work it should show that the `wlan0` device is `unblocked` in the the SOFT and HARD colums. If the device isn't connecting due to this issue then it will show as `blocked` in SOFT column.

This can only be remedied by mounting the image and changing the config as per [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/127705/automatically-run-rfkill-unblock-on-startup), or by booting it and logging in on the console and typing:

```
sudo rfkill unblock wifi
```

Answer (score 1):

I have this issue often, from what i observed so far these things help most-
1)disable bluetooth
2)use new wpa supplicant file
3)setup wifi with sudo raspi-config, and safely reboot

these things happen on my pi4, pi3, pi zero w and w2... i sometimes need to switch between 2 networks, and problem usually happens after i want to switch to new one. Setting it up in window manager often does not work...

my sample wpa i use for every pi:

country=sk

update_config=1

ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant

network={

scan_ssid=1

ssid="ssidname"

psk="ssidpw"

}